# Execute storyboard when databound property changes

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Just this. I want that when the databound property Text of a TextBlock for example changes, an animation is performed to give some feedback to the user. How can this be done?? thanks!

Comment: Are you using MVVM? If yes then you could use a Messenger in your property setter to send a message out to a helper class which then starts the animation on your View. Or you could use Transitions and visual states.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a way to do it using a PropertyChangedTrigger

```
<Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>    
    <ec:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding KnownMeaning}" >
         <eim:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="StaticResource Storyboard2}"/>
    </ec:PropertyChangedTrigger>
</Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

There may be a more elegant solution, but I think this is pretty straightforward

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add event to ViewModel and start animation ([Storyboard.Begin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)) in code-behind. Or even do it without extra event by adding handler of ViewModel.PropertyChanged in code-behind.

More advanced options are listed here:
[Re: How to Annimate (Storyboard.Begin() ) in MVVM](http://forums.silverlight.net/post/357852.aspx).